# Selenium webdriver in Colab is not launching a Chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

My code is running successfully without any error but a browser is not getting launched. Please find code below:

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver

sys.path.insert(0,'C:/Users/vinu0/chromedriver_win32')

options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
options.add_argument('start-maximized') # 
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
```

Comment: Why do you think the browser is not getting lunched?

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: comment headless and check it's open or not?